# Controlling which CMS environment is to be used at compile time

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am building an iOS application which integrates with a Rails CMS. The CMS is running in multiple environments (development, staging, preprod and production). Currently the Info.plist file contains a key that stores a string value which corresponds to and determines which CMS environment the app communicates with. This is not ideal as each time the application needs to be archived for ad-hoc or App Store distribution the value must be changed (which is far too easy to forget). It is also easy to forget to change this value back to development after performing the archive process.

My question is what would be a better approach to control which CMS environment the application communicates with.

The next approach I was thinking of taking was to have the key in the Info.plist point to an environment variable. I could then edit each action of the project's scheme (Run, Test, Archive) in Xcode to set that environment variable as appropriate. The problem with that approach is that the scheme setups are not included in source control. Also only one scheme is used for creating both ad-hoc and App Store archives (which both need to use different CMS environments).